# django-admin-tools-stats : Reverse for 'admin-charts' not found. 'admin-charts' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

just installed django-admin-tools-stats.

gives me the following error:

Reverse for 'admin-charts' not found. 'admin-charts' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using django-admin-charts than django-admin-tools-stats.
I got same bug as you got.
I fixed it by adding this path.

```
urlpatterns = [

path('admin_tools_stats/', include('admin_tools_stats.urls')),#added this path
path('admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ....
]
```

django-admin-charts and django-admin-tools-stats use almost same package and do almost same functions.
https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-charts/
[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing, I just removed it and took another path, it was turning out too be too big a headache. well, thanks for sharing, I will mark this as the answer, but I am not 100% certain it is!